# Unknow CA in rabbitmq Operator (mTLS)

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, rabbitmq, ssl-certificate, mtls

I have working rabbitMq cluster created with rabbitmq Operator. Clients is connecting with TLS. Now i try to configure cluster to use mTLS.

I generate CA certs with tool provided by rabbitmq [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/tls-gen) (basic option). Cert are genereted with CN=rabbitmq.rabbitmq.svc which is the name of rabbitmq service. Add CA cert as secret and add properties to cluster

```
  tls:
      secretName: rabbit-tls-secret
      caSecretName: rabbitmq-ca
```

If i try to connect to rabbit using .p12 certificate which was generated with CA certificate, I have "connection refused" in client and "Unknown CA" error in rabbitmq logs

What do I wrong? When i check /usr/local/share/ca-certificates on rabbitmq-server-0 pod there is no certificates there.